# Indent paragraph of text printed by a bash script

Tags: bash, text-formatting

I have a bash script that echoes paragraphs of text. I want them to be indented.

Example:

```
echo "Something"
echo -e "\tfoo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo"
```

Will print something like this:

```
Something
      foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

But what I want is this:

```
Something
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

I prefer to avoid having to line-break many such paragraphs by hand.

I've seen all sorts of techniques using `sed` and so on, but I need to rely on shell builtins only (should be as simple as possible).

**UPDATE**
Put it this way- how do the `man` pages (for any random command) format all those paragraphs so nicely? Surely they were not line-breaked by hand? And I assume they didn't use anything other than builtins when documenting the basic commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `fmt` (from GNU Coreutils)

```
{ echo "Something"
echo -e "\tfoo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo"
} | fmt
Something
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
    foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
```

You can add an optional `-w n` to change the length of the wrapped lines to `n`

Comment: Thanks. Is `fmt` an "addon", or can I rely on it being available in most linuxes? (I use Ubuntu and I see that I have it though). Is "GNU CoreUtils" part of the "core" of the OS, if that is the right terminology?

Comment: Also do you know why if I put it on one line `{ echo -e "foo" } | fmt` it says "syntax error: unexpected end of file" but your way works?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I would expect that CoreUtils would be part of any GNU/Linux system since it provides basic command such as `ls`, `rm` etc. To make the command group work in a one-liner you need to add a semicolon: `{ echo -e "foo"; } | fmt`

Answer (score 7):

```
somecommand | fold | awk '{ print "\t" $0 }'
```

This would take the output from `somecommand` (for example `echo`), send it through `fold`, which would fold it at 80 characters (use `fold -w N` to fold at `N` characters). Then the `awk` script will print each line indented by a tab character.

Doing folding in pure `bash` is bound to result in a more complicated script.

Comment: Thanks. Is `awk` an "addon", or can I rely on it being available in most linuxes? (I use Ubuntu and I see that I have it though)

Comment: @lonix I don't know much about Linux, but both `fold` and `awk` are POSIX standard utilities.

Comment: @lonix To rephrase my previous comment from a few years ago: `fold` and `awk` are expected to be available on any Unix system. Some Linux admins may choose to install crippled systems without all basic tools. On those systems, you may not even find a complete set of manuals installed. On the other hand, on non-Linux systems, these tools are standard and always installed. What may be missing on a non-Linux system is the `bash` shell.

Comment: ```shell
somecommand | fold | sed 's/^/\t/'
```
is alse possible

Comment: @AntonKorneychuk Yes, if you're using GNU `sed`. Other `sed` implementations do not recognize `\t` as a tab character.  In some shells, you could use `... | sed $'s/^/\t/'` instead.  With standard `sed` you would need to insert a literal tab character, e.g. by pressing `Ctrl+V` and then `Tab` or use `... | sed -e 's/^/@/' -e 'y/@/\t/'` assuming `@` does not otherwise occur in the data.

Comment: @Kusalananda cool! You are a real hacker! I'll know, thanks.
I tested only on debian's `sed` & default `sed` from macos on zsh & bash.